# Alternative to substring

Tags: java, arraylist, substring

I have a strange problem when adding a value to a String array which is later involved in an array sort using a hash map. I have a filename XFR900a, and the XFR900 part is added to the array using the following code;

```
private ArrayList<String> Types = new ArrayList<String>();

...

Types.add(name.substring(0,(name.length() - 1));
System.out.println(name.substring(0,(name.length() - 1));
```

I even print the line which gives "XFR900", however the array sort later on behaves differently when I use the following code instead;

```
Types.add("XFR900");
System.out.println(name.substring(0,(name.length() - 1));
```

which is simply the substring part done manually, very confusing.

Are there any good alternatives to substring, as there must be some odd non ascii character in there?

Phil

UPDATE

Thanks for your comments everyone. Here is some of the code that later compares the string;

```
    for (int i=0;i< matchedArray.size();i++){

        //run through the arrays
        if (last == matchedArray.get(i)) {
            //add arrays to a data array
            ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
            data.add(matchedArray1.get(i));
            data.add(matchedArray2.get(i));
            data.add(matchedArray3.get(i));
            data.add(matchedArray4.get(i));
            data.add(matchedArray5.get(i));
            //put into hash map 
            map.put(matchedArray.get(i), data);
        }
        else {
            //TODO
            System.out.println("DO NOT MATCH :" + last + "-" + matchedArray.get(i));
```

As you can see I have added a test System.out.println("DO NOT MATCH" ... and below is some the output;

DO NOT MATCH :FR99-XFR900
DO NOT MATCH :XFR900-XFR900

I only run the substring on the XFR900a filename. The problem is that for the test line to be printed last != matchedArray.get(i) however they are then the same when printed out to the display.

Phil

Comment: Side comment - Java naming conventions: variables start in lower case (Types => types).

Comment: substring is the method you want. If you have a problem with strange, non-ASCII characters using a different method will have the same problem. I suggest you investigate exactly what is happening in more detail.

Comment: The possibility that substring somehow messes up the input seems very low to me. I'd rather check my code twice before accusing API functions from misbehaving. Also Java convention for variables is first lowercase, hence types instead of Types

Comment: What do you mean by "behaves differently"?  How are the two sorted lists different (manual vs. coded)?

Comment: Can you post the differences in the sorted output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use the `==` operator to compare the content of strings. `==` checks if it is the same object. Write `last.equals(matchedArray.get(i))` instead. The `equals()` method checks if to object are equal, not if they are the same. In case of `String` it checks if the two strings consists of the same characters. This might eliminate your strange behaviour.

PS: The behaviour of `==` on string is a little unpredictable because the java virtual machine does some optimization. If two strings are equal it is possible that the jvm uses the same object for both. This is possible because `String` objects are immutable anyway. This would explain the difference in behaviour if you write down the substring manually. In the one case the jvm optimizes, in the other it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals()` rather than `==` because they are strings!

```
if (last.equals(matchedArray.get(i))) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use == operator if you wanted to check the value since operator will check the Object reference equality, use equals operator which check on the value not the reference i.e.

```
for (int i=0;i< matchedArray.size();i++){
```

//run through the arrays
    if (last.equals(matchedArray.get(i))) { // Line edited
        //add arrays to a data array
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
        data.add(matchedArray1.get(i));
        data.add(matchedArray2.get(i));
        data.add(matchedArray3.get(i));
        data.add(matchedArray4.get(i));
        data.add(matchedArray5.get(i));
        //put into hash map 
        map.put(matchedArray.get(i), data);
    }
    else {
        //TODO
        System.out.println("DO NOT MATCH :" + last + "-" + matchedArray.get(i));